# Laravel 5.1: How to use middleware in an implicit controller?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-middleware

I want to check an authentication to access a controller named FoodController, and this controller access will allow only some users, therefore I create a middleware and assign it to the implicit controller routing on route.php file. But it shows an error -

```
ErrorException in Router.php line 612:
strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

The codes are given below:

Route.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function(){
    Route::controller('home','HomeController');
    Route::controller('food',['middleware' => 'fm', 'uses' => 'FoodController']);
});
```

kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'fm' => \App\Http\Middleware\FoodAuthentication::class,
];
```

FoodAuthentication.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FoodAuthentication
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->role!=2) {
            return redirect('home');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant put an array to Route::controller. Just add

```
public function __construct() {
       $this->middleware('fm');
  }
```

to your FoodController class

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
You cannot add middleware directly in implicit controllers.
Follow the below link:
http://arunkp.in/adding-middleware-in-implicit-controllers/